# Change user settings in Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, settings

I'm trying to change my user settings for Sublime Text 3 so that word wrap is disabled by default. However, I'm running into some problems. Sublime Text doesn't let you change the default settings under Preferences -> Settings. I know this and I've read every StackOverflow question that already tells me this. The answer to all of those questions is always

"Go to Preferences -> Settings - User"

or

"navigate to C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings and modify the file there."

The problem I'm having is that neither of these options seem to work. I have no Preferences -> Settings - User option (only Settings, Settings - Syntax Specific, and Settings - Distraction Free). And when I try to C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings, no such file exists. There isn't even a Sublime Text 3 folder under Roaming.

I'm using Windows 10 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The user preferences file doesn't exist until you have edited and saved your user preferences or otherwise manually created it.

On older versions of ST, it was in the Preferences menu as Settings - User, it is now Preferences -> Settings, and the pane on the right.